# Volume of neighborhood after smooth mapping?

Tags: differential-geometry

If I have a map $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ mapping $x \mapsto y$ and in particular $x_0 \mapsto y_0$.

I have an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $y_0$, call it $U(y_0)$.

If $F$ is smooth and invertible, what is a good approximation of the volume of $F^{-1}(U)$, in terms of the original volume?

Is it the volume of $U(y_0)$ multiplied by the Jacobian:

$$\left| \frac{\partial F^{-1} (y)}{\partial y} \right| $$

evaluated at $y_0$?

Background: $F$ is actually a neural network, and I'm working on its learning algorithm.

Comment: Only if $F$ is linear, but it probably is not.

Comment: Are you wanting an approximation for small $\epsilon$ and assuming $F$ is $C^1$?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say approximation.  And F is smooth.

Comment: $n<m$ so that $F$ is diffeomorphic onto $F({\bf R}^n)$ ?

Comment: if $F$ was a $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ function you would have to look at the determinant of the differential at the point.

Comment: Why does it matter whether $n < m$?  Assume $m = n$ if it helps (question edited to $m = n$).

Comment: let $g(x) = f(x_0 + x) - f(x_0)=  M x + \mathcal{O}(\|x\|^2)$ where $M$ is the differential at the point. the volume of the Image of a $\epsilon$ cube by $g$ has a volume of $\approx$ $\det(M)\epsilon$ (with an error  $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ since $g$ is $C^2$)

Comment: can I ask now some precision on where it appears during the studies of neural networks ?

Comment: @user1952009:  an associative NN would map $x_0$ to $y_0$, and if I want to strengthen this association, I want more points near $x_0$ to be mapped to $y_0$'s neighborhood, thus achieving generalization via proximity.  This is a special-purpose learning algorithm.

Comment: F is one-to-one ? If so why do you consider $F^{-1}U$ instead of $F(U)$ ?

Comment: @YanKingYin : you mean in a unsupervised learning algorithm for a neural network $F$, you'd ask it to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^K |det(\partial F(x_i))|$ where $(x_i)_{1 \ldots K}$ are the samples to be "learned" by the neural network ?

Comment: @Alphago: Yes F is 1-to-1, but I want to consider the volume in x's domain.

Comment: @user1952009:  Yes, something like that.  The network is feedforward, and it learns the associative map from inputs $x_i$ to outputs $y_i$. We do not know the $x_i$ and $y_i$'s, only when the output is right a reward is given.

Comment: if want help you'll have to explain better : your problem, your objective function, your neural network topology, your datas.

Comment: The main question is here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724411/associative-neural-network-learning-algorithm-based-on-proximity